# How can I talk about priority inversion if it's impossible to specify priority?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, semantics, process-scheduling, synchronization

In the paper:

> Leslie Lamport: [What It Means for a Concurrent Program to
>   Satisfy a Speciﬁcation: Why No One Has Speciﬁed Priority](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#priority); *ACM Symp Principles of Programming Languages*, (POPL-12):78-83, 1985.

Lamport shows that "...existing specifications that claim to describe prioirty are either vacuous or else too restrictive to be implemented...", and in the conclusion says

> Waiting is an implementation-level concept that I feel cannot be expressed in a general way.

Yet, we have vigorous conversations about [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) in real operating systems.  Take, for example, this argument I found between [Victor Yodaiken](http://archive.linuxgizmos.com/yodaiken-against-priority-inheritance-a/) and [Doug Locke](http://archive.linuxgizmos.com/priority-inheritance-the-real-story-a/) about whether it is a good or bad idea to implement [priority inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inheritance) in a real-time Linux scheduler.  Yodaiken cites the classic Lampson and Redell paper about monitors (*CACM*, 23(2):105-117, 1980) to describe what priority inversion is.

I *thought* I had a concrete but informal notion of priority inversion and priority inheritance, and have been teaching these concepts to unwitting undergraduates for over a decade.  Should I stop trying to teach about priority since the concept is apparently vacuous?